# Alternative to TimeSpan.FromHours for perfomance

Tags: c#

I read that TimeSpan.FromHours method is considered slower ( http://www.dotnetperls.com/timespan ) and I should be using the TimeStamp constructor.

But how I'm going to do that for the following scenario considering the fact that I shouldn't be using `.FromHours` method :

```
 TimeSpan ts = TimesSpan.FromHours(double.Parse(stringVal));
 double tHours = ts.TotalHours;
 double min = ts.Minutes;
```

Comment: Truly? In what app would you ever need to compute `TimeSpan.FromHours` so much that performance is an issue?

Comment: What makes you think that you shouldn't be using it? Are you having performance issues in your app which you think is caused by `TimeSpan.FromHours` ?

Comment: This is not only highly unlikely to ever count, it also assumes that you have the input ready and checked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That benchmark is over 100,000,000 iterations and suggests that it is twice as slow as the constructor. Unless you can prove with your own benchmarks that the "overhead" is a problem for your application, I would suggest you stick with the `FromHours` method as it is far more readable and less ambiguous.